# Electromagnetic induction in a system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

In a two body system both carrying current thus constituting a magnetic field, so will the mutual inductance of the system be equal to the mutual inductance due to body 1 on body 2 and vice-versa. If that is true, does that mean flux due to body 1 on body 2 is equal to flux due to body 2 on body 1?

Comment: No, it will also depend on their respective currents.

Comment: If current is equal then?

Comment: In case of solenoid, it will also depend on the number of turns